# Can't add this into gradle>>> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'

Tags: android, gradle, admob, ads

Trying to add admob into app. Started new project and started directions from:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Added > compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+' < to the gradle and synced, and now I cannot RUN and I get this error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
C:\Users\Emmi\Desktop\Android2015\adsplease\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:\Users\Emmi\Desktop\Android2015\adsplease\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to force usage
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library C:\Users\Emmi\Desktop\Android2015\adsplease\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.5.87\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" to force usage
```

Comment: `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library GooglePlay` the error message is pretty simple. Just change your project to `minSdkVersion 9`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `google_play_service` with SDK `>= 8` and `< 9`, then you have to use the following properties in your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk 
  tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.all,com.google.android.gms.ads,com.google.android.gms,
        com.google.android.gms.analytics,com.google.android.gms.appindexing,
        com.google.android.gms.appinvite,com.google.android.gms.appstate,com.google.android.gms.cast,com.google.android.gms.drive,
        com.google.android.gms.fitness,com.google.android.gms.location,com.google.android.gms.maps,com.google.android.gms.games,
        com.google.android.gms.gcm,com.google.android.gms.identity,com.google.android.gms.nearby,com.google.android.gms.panorama,
        com.google.android.gms.plus,com.google.android.gms.safetynet,com.google.android.gms.wallet,com.google.android.gms.wearable"
        />
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in
>   library

Are you sure your project minSdk is not 7, in AndroidManifest or gradle file? If so, increase it to 9.

Comment: for who is using Android Studio (mine is v1.5), he can find this setting in Build -> Edit Flavors -> Modules -> App edit the field "Min Sdk Version"

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase your min sdk value of your app to 9, because the playservices need this. Thats what the message says.

You can do this in your apps gradle build file.

Don't do it in your Manifest of the application, because gradle will overwrite it with the value from the gradle build file.

Here is an simple minimum example of an apps modul build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
}
```